# change keypair in an active instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-keystone

Openstack version  - Pike

In Openstack there is no provision to change the keypair of any active instance. Queens and Rocky give the option in rebuild command, but that will re-create the instance again.
1. Is there any way to change the keypair of instance without re-creating it?
2. Why there has been no provision, is there any security threat to change keyair in active instance?

Kindly if anyone give answer to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1843708, one of the commands below should work:

```
 nova --os-compute-api-version 2.54   rebuild  --key-name  key1 instance1 IMAGE_NAME
```

OR

```
 openstack --os-compute-api-version 2.54 server rebuild --image "IMAGE_NAME" --key-name key1 instance1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no "official" way to do that in Openstack.

I wrote an article about the 2 options available of how to change the keypair:

https://osie.io/blog/changing-the-ssh-keypair-for-an-active-openstack-instance